# Keeping both DataFrame indexes on merge

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

I'm sure this question must have already been answered somewhere but I couldn't find an answer that suits my case.
I have 2 pandas DataFrames

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'A1':[1,2,3], 'A2':[2,4,6]}, index=['a','b','c'])
b = pd.DataFrame({'A1':[3,5,6], 'A2':[3,6,9]}, index=['a','c','d'])
```

I want to merge them in order to obtain something like

```
result = pd.DataFrame({
    'A1' : [3,2,5,6],
    'A2' : [3,4,6,9]
}, index=['a','b','c','d'])
```

Basically, I want a new df with the union of both indexes. Where indexes match, the value in each column should be updated with the one from the second df (in this case `b`). Where there is no match the value is taken from the starting df (in this case `a`).
I tried with merge(), join() and concat() but I could not manage to obtain this result.

Comment: ```index``` b only appears in df ```a``` with values ```2,4``` respectively. Why in your result ```index``` b takes the values from df ```b``` of ```index``` c?

Comment: Shouldn't the result you want be `pd.DataFrame({'A1' : [3,2,5,6],'A2' : [3,4,6,9]},index=['a','b','c','d'])` according to your description? (i.e., index b should correspond to (2, 4) as @sophocles said)

Comment: You are right It was wrong, i corrected it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `pd.concat` to create one dataframe (`b` being the first one as it is `b` that has a priority for it's values to be kept over `a`), and then drop the duplicated index:

Using your sample data:

```
c = pd.concat([b,a])
c[~c.index.duplicated()].sort_index()
```

prints:

```
   A1  A2
a   3   3
b   2   4
c   5   6
d   6   9
```