# Merging Dataframes keeping all rows and avoiding duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Scenario:** 2 dataframes, DF1 with more rows with is used as base. DF2 with less rows (some rows are the same as DF1) to be merged to DF1.

DF1:

```
+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+---------+---------------+
| ID    | SC1         | SC2         | SC3         | ID_S1 | ID_S2 | ID_S3 | Level 4 | distance_b    |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+---------+---------------+
| 33    | 10962.47899 | 7875.111012 | 706052.0191 | 108   | 109   | 1     | 3152242 | -0.900145196  |
| 55    | 2236.893557 | 6348.118443 | 303822.4207 | 248   | 249   | 1     | 33200   | 0.030865582   |
| 129   | 585.418248  | 1501.098752 | 27868.29414 | 248   | 249   | 1     | 33200   | 0.100982593   |
| 217   | 36499       | 2991        | 1396206.236 | 248   | 249   | 1     | 33200   | -0.072661146  |
| 282   | 1856        | 0           | 3923696.952 | 248   | 249   | 1     | 33200   | -0.314488715  |
| 316   | 832810.1761 | 243967.7219 | 8746827.687 | 48    | 109   | 50    | 21200   | -0.074955486  |
| 335   | 40702849    | 253302      | 7351077.4   | 40    | 41    | 42    | 21100   | 6.21917301    |
| 522   | 9577.085592 | 14993.40441 | 1596694.304 | 108   | 109   | 1     | 3152242 | -0.863500166  |
| 546   | 25.811657   | 73.251343   | 4095.608701 | 248   | 249   | 1     | 33200   | 0.161677854   |
| 1149  | 512.155964  | 1428.380036 | 118129.9309 | 248   | 249   | 1     | 33200   | 1.83147728    |
| 1203  | 1300        | 22000       | 1422672.048 | 248   | 249   | 1     | 33200   | -0.308400239  |
| 901   | 294000      | 899000      | 1675000     | 68    | 69    | 1     | 33200   | 434.51        |
| 22090 | 1965.379893 | 4910.304107 | 6875.684    | 248   | 249   | 1     | 33200   | 434.51        |
| 22822 | 20392       | 54543       | 74935       | 248   | 249   | 1     | 33200   | 434.51        |
| 23568 | 112.742682  | 350.618318  | 463.361     | 68    | 69    | 1     | 31200   | 817.53        |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+---------+---------------+
```

DF2:

```
+-------+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| ID    | ProdTotal   | Intensity_f | distance_f    |
+-------+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| 901   |  900.10     | 0.015755513 | -0.735752608  |
| 4634  |  4,634.03   | 0.489616194 | 7.211716147   |
| 6689  |  6,689.10   | 0.013318224 | -0.776630184  |
| 7078  |  7,077.93   | 0.015727018 | -0.736230529  |
| 7126  |  7,125.69   | 0.014249219 | -0.761015778  |
| 7477  |  7,476.93   | 0.592594743 | 8.938845738   |
| 8033  |  8,039.22   | 0.489616194 | 7.211716147   |
| 10929 |  10,928.14  | 0.022427961 | -0.623844047  |
| 13249 |  13,249.16  | 0.015384817 | -0.741969827  |
| 19645 |  19,646.83  | 0.013318224 | -0.776630184  |
| 22090 |  22,089.69  | 0.013318224 | -0.776630184  |
| 22822 |  22,822.00  | 0.044975631 | -0.245680358  |
| 23568 |  23,568.00  | 0.036043199 | -0.395492793  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+---------------+
```

Objective: To have all rows in the final DF, keeping as much data as possible without duplicates:

```
+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+---------+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
|  ID   |     SC1     |     SC2     |     SC3     | ID_S1 | ID_S2 | ID_S3 | Level 4 |  distance_b  |  ProdTotal  | Intensity_f |  distance_f  |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+---------+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
|    33 | 10962.47899 | 7875.111012 | 706052.0191 | 108   | 109   | 1     | 3152242 | -0.900145196 | nan         | nan         | nan          |
|    55 | 2236.893557 | 6348.118443 | 303822.4207 | 248   | 249   | 1     | 33200   | 0.030865582  | nan         | nan         | nan          |
|   129 | 585.418248  | 1501.098752 | 27868.29414 | 248   | 249   | 1     | 33200   | 0.100982593  | nan         | nan         | nan          |
|   217 | 36499       | 2991        | 1396206.236 | 248   | 249   | 1     | 33200   | -0.072661146 | nan         | nan         | nan          |
|   282 | 1856        | 0           | 3923696.952 | 248   | 249   | 1     | 33200   | -0.314488715 | nan         | nan         | nan          |
|   316 | 832810.1761 | 243967.7219 | 8746827.687 | 48    | 109   | 50    | 21200   | -0.074955486 | nan         | nan         | nan          |
|   335 | 40702849    | 253302      | 7351077.4   | 40    | 41    | 42    | 21100   | 6.21917301   | nan         | nan         | nan          |
|   522 | 9577.085592 | 14993.40441 | 1596694.304 | 108   | 109   | 1     | 3152242 | -0.863500166 | nan         | nan         | nan          |
|   546 | 25.811657   | 73.251343   | 4095.608701 | 248   | 249   | 1     | 33200   | 0.161677854  | nan         | nan         | nan          |
|  1149 | 512.155964  | 1428.380036 | 118129.9309 | 248   | 249   | 1     | 33200   | 1.83147728   | nan         | nan         | nan          |
|  1203 | 1300        | 22000       | 1422672.048 | 248   | 249   | 1     | 33200   | -0.308400239 | nan         | nan         | nan          |
|   901 | 294000      | 899000      | 1675000     | 68    | 69    | 1     | 33200   | 434.51       |  900.10     | 0.015755513 | -0.735752608 |
| 22090 | 1965.379893 | 4910.304107 | 6875.684    | 248   | 249   | 1     | 33200   | 434.51       |  22,089.69  | 0.013318224 | -0.776630184 |
| 22822 | 20392       | 54543       | 74935       | 248   | 249   | 1     | 33200   | 434.51       |  22,822.00  | 0.044975631 | -0.245680358 |
| 23568 | 112.742682  | 350.618318  | 463.361     | 68    | 69    | 1     | 31200   | 817.53       |  23,568.00  | 0.036043199 | -0.395492793 |
|  4634 | nan         | nan         | nan         | nan   | nan   | nan   | nan     | nan          |  4,634.03   | 0.489616194 | 7.211716147  |
|  6689 | nan         | nan         | nan         | nan   | nan   | nan   | nan     | nan          |  6,689.10   | 0.013318224 | -0.776630184 |
|  7078 | nan         | nan         | nan         | nan   | nan   | nan   | nan     | nan          |  7,077.93   | 0.015727018 | -0.736230529 |
|  7126 | nan         | nan         | nan         | nan   | nan   | nan   | nan     | nan          |  7,125.69   | 0.014249219 | -0.761015778 |
|  7477 | nan         | nan         | nan         | nan   | nan   | nan   | nan     | nan          |  7,476.93   | 0.592594743 | 8.938845738  |
|  8033 | nan         | nan         | nan         | nan   | nan   | nan   | nan     | nan          |  8,039.22   | 0.489616194 | 7.211716147  |
| 10929 | nan         | nan         | nan         | nan   | nan   | nan   | nan     | nan          |  10,928.14  | 0.022427961 | -0.623844047 |
| 13249 | nan         | nan         | nan         | nan   | nan   | nan   | nan     | nan          |  13,249.16  | 0.015384817 | -0.741969827 |
| 19645 | nan         | nan         | nan         | nan   | nan   | nan   | nan     | nan          |  19,646.83  | 0.013318224 | -0.776630184 |
+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+---------+--------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Test 1: I tried this operation using df.merge with a left join. The issue is that in this case it only keeps the rows of DF1. While this fills the data for IDs that are in both, data from DF2 is lost.

```
output_DF = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='ID')
```

Test 2: Other types of joins (right, outer) also result in lost data.

Test 3: Using concat, it is possible to get all the data, but there are duplicate rows, where the first entry has DF1 data and second entry has DF2 data. As per other question suggestion ([Keeping both DataFrame indexes on merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72068789/keeping-both-dataframe-indexes-on-merge)) it could be removed via index drop, but that would also drop the data from DF2.

```
outputdf2 = pd.concat([df1,df2])
outputdf2 [~outputdf2 .index.duplicated()].sort_index()
```

Question: What is the correct way to perform this kind of operation?

Comment: Have you tried with `how='outer'`?

Comment: With the provided example `how='outer'` does give the expected output. Please double check and make sure to provide an example which results in "*lost data*" with those commands.

Comment: ```pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id', how='outer')``` ?

Comment: I don't think it's even possible to lose data on an outer merge. You could have duplicates, but not with this dataset.